# Find positive integer that can't be expressed by [x/2] y x*y?

Tags: algorithm

There is an expression: [x/2] + y + x * y, x and y are positive integers, [x/2] mean rounding down to integer, for example, [3/2] = 1. Some positive integers can't be expressed by this expression, for example, 1, 3. Now, the question is how to quickly find out the first 40 numbers?

when x = 1, the expression is 2*y, so the number must not be an even number. 
when y = 1, the expression is [x/2] + x + 1, it not include 3*n.
then I tried as follow:

```
int64_t givean( int n )
{
    if( n == 1 ) return 1;
    if( n == 2 ) return 3;
    int i = 3;
    int count = 2;
    while( true ){
        int64_t m = i * 3;
        bool ok = true;
        for( int x = 3; x <= ( 2*m - 2 ) / 3; x++ ){
           if( ( x / 2 + x + 1 ) >= m ){
               ok = false;
           }
           if( !( ( m - x/2 ) % ( x + 1 ) ) ){
               ok = false;
               break;
           }
        }
        if( ok && ++count == n ){
           return m;
        }
        i += 2;
    }
}
```

the first 7 numbers can be quickly found, find the eighth number cost about 2 minutes...
the first 8 numbers are:

```
1
3
15
63
4095
65535
262143
1073741823
```

is there any other high-performance algorithm to solve this problem?

Comment: -1 can you explain a bit more and what have you tried

Comment: Fun fact: the first six numbers are 1, 3, 15, 63, 4095, and 65535. I don't believe you'll be able to find the first 40 with bruteforce. This is *not* a trivial problem. (Also, I couldn't find the sequence or the (log2(n+1)) sequence on OEIS: props to finding a brand new integer sequence!)

Comment: By the way, just for clarification, the given equation is equivalent to `[x/2] + y * (x+1)`, right?

Comment: Also, this is probably more suited for MathOverflow.

Comment: After doing some math, I've determined that any non-solutions must either be equal to 1 (2^1 - 1), or of the form `2^(2k) - 1` for some positive integer `k`. So, the 40th solution is at least 2^78-1, and is probably much bigger than that.

Comment: yes it equivalent to [x/2] + y * (x+1)

Comment: If my hunch is right, the 40th such number is 4^10498005-1, which is a stunningly huge number. (But, I might be wrong -- this is only based on some quick OEIS searching and a minimal amount of math).

Comment: With some manipulation I have just confirmed that. Yes, the 40th number is 4^10498005-1. You would not be able to find that with a brute force approach. In fact, the 50th such number is not yet known!

Comment: If you post this on [math.se], I can give my analysis there.

Comment: thanks, I have already post it. http://mathoverflow.net/questions/139287/find-positive-integer-that-cant-be-expressed-by-x-2-y-xy

Comment: I'm sorry I said MathOverflow earlier. I meant [math.se]. I don't think the problem is appropriate for MathOverflow as that site is for professional academic mathematics (just look at the other problems there). It is probably better suited for [math.se].

Comment: @JianZhang: And, unsurprisingly, it was closed. Please, accept my apologies. The question is reopened here, so I will answer here.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/466385/find-positive-integer-that-cant-be-expressed-by-x-2-y-xy

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This very innocent problem turns out to be quite tricky. Let's look at the case of `x` odd and `x` even separately.

If `x` is odd, write `x = 2k - 1` for some positive integer `k`. Then, we have

```
n = (k-1) + y * 2k = 2ky + k - 1 = y(2k+1) - 1
```

Note that `y` is any positive integer, and `2k+1` is any odd integer greater than 1. The expression `y*(2k+1)` can thus generate *any* integer which has an odd prime factor. Thus, `n+1` has a solution if it has an odd prime factor, so in order for it to be a non-solution, `n+1` must either be 1 (which has no prime factors at all), or a power of two. Since `n+1` is illegal (it would make `n` 0, which can't happen since `x` and `y` are positive integers), we conclude that all non-solutions `n` must have `n+1` be a power of two.

Thus, we can write all our non-solutions as `2^m-1` for some positive integer `m`.

---

Now let's look at the case of even `x`. We have

```
n = 2^m-1 = k + y * (2k+1) = k + 2ky + y
```

Look at `2n+1`:

```
2n+1 = 2^(m+1)-1 = 2k + 4ky + 2y + 1 = (2k + 1)(2y + 1)
```

`2k+1` and `2y+1` are arbitrary odd numbers. Because `2n+1` is always odd, we conclude that `2n+1` must be composite. Every solution (for `x` even) must have this form. Thus, `n` is a non-solution iff `n+1` is a power of two, and `2n+1` is prime.

In fact, this implies that `2n+1` is a Mersenne prime, and so the first 40 non-solutions correspond to the first 40 Mersenne primes (given a Mersenne prime `Mp`, the corresponding non-solution is `(Mp-1)/2`).

---

The fastest algorithm to find the first 40 Mersenne primes is to ask the Internet. (Seriously -- finding Mersenne primes is hard work; the 50th Mersenne prime is not even known yet!) The exponents for the first 42 Mersenne primes is given by [OEIS A000043](http://oeis.org/A000043/list):

```
1       2
2       3
3       5
4       7
5       13
6       17
7       19
8       31
9       61
10      89
11      107
12      127
13      521
14      607
15      1279
16      2203
17      2281
18      3217
19      4253
20      4423
21      9689
22      9941
23      11213
24      19937
25      21701
26      23209
27      44497
28      86243
29      110503
30      132049
31      216091
32      756839
33      859433
34      1257787
35      1398269
36      2976221
37      3021377
38      6972593
39      13466917
40      20996011
41      24036583
42      25964951
```

and so, for example, the 40th non-solution is 2^(20996011-1)-1, which is a really big number.

Comment: Thanks very much! It's a very nice analysis! it benefited me.